# While using flexbox, how can i make 3 buttons which are in flex column slide out left into view on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lcmc3k0/10/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.mainCont {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  min-height: 5em;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 6em;
}

.allButton,
.onButton,
.offButton {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#circleAll {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: .5em;
  height: .5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>testpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!--main container-->
    <div class='mainCont'>
      <!--heading container-->
      <h3 id="twitchHead">TWITCH STREAMERS</h3>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class='allButton'><span id="circleAll"></span><span id="onAll">All</span></button>
        <button class='onButton'><span id="circleAll"></span><span id="on1">Online</span></button>
        <button class='offButton'><span id="circleAll"></span><span id="off1">Offline</span></button>
      </div>
</body>
```

So I want only the blue circles to show intially. Then when the user hovers over one of them, it slides out left and reveals if its All/online/offline button. I want to be able to do this only one at a time.

I know how to slide out and do hover, but what I can't figure out is how to hide the button and text and just show the blue dot part of the button only when the mouse is not over it.

How can i best accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish it. You shouldn't use duplicate ID's so I changed `circleAll` to a class and also added `.btn` and `.text` classes for easier targeting. Edit further to your liking and also you can add prefixed styles for Flexbox and transitions for wider browser support.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.mainCont {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  min-height: 5em;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.allButton,
.onButton,
.offButton {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.circleAll {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: .5em;
  height: .5em;
  margin-right: 0px;
  transition: margin-right .3s ease 0s;
}
.btn:hover .circleAll,
.btn:focus .circleAll {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.text {
  max-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  transition: max-width .3s ease 0s;
}
.btn:hover .text,
.btn:focus .text {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--main container-->
  <div class='mainCont'>
    <!--heading container-->
    <h3 id="twitchHead">TWITCH STREAMERS</h3>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class='allButton btn'>
        <span class="circleAll"></span>
        <span id="onAll" class="text">All</span>
      </button>
      <button class='onButton btn'>
        <span class="circleAll"></span>
        <span id="on1" class="text">Online</span>
      </button>
      <button class='offButton btn'>
        <span class="circleAll"></span>
        <span id="off1" class="text">Offline</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works! looks like i was on the right track but just couldn't figure out how to do the transition properly. thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!